# How to hide a bootstrap modal if there is no content inside it in Angular4

Tags: angular, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I am working in an Angular 4 e-commerce application ,In this I need to hide a bootstrap modal when there is no product in the cart.

when user selected some product that are added to the mycart modal screen.User can delete products from mycart .

In this case I want to do like this ,When there is no product in mycart ,if user clicked on the mycart icon it should not open the modal.

currently it open a empty modal screen .

appComponent.html

```
<div class="modal fade modalstyle" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header headerHeight text-white " style="background:rgb(0, 0, 0);font-weight:bold">
        <h6 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">My Cart Items</h6>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div *ngFor="let products of mycart;let i =index;">
          <div class="container col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 paddingforimage">
                <img [src]="products['ITEM_IMAGE_PATH']">
              </div>
              <div class="text-info col-sm-6">
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_QTY}} &times; {{products?.ITEM_PRICE}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.ITEM_DESC}}</h6>
                </span>
                <span>
                  <h6>{{products?.TOTAL_AMT}} &#8377;</h6>
                </span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-1 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="close closebtn" aria-label="Close" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" (click)="detele_My_Cart(products?.ITEM_CODE)">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
        <div class=" container row col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>SHIPPING</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">0 &#8377;</div>
          <hr>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <strong>TOTAL</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">{{my_Cart_Total_Amount}} &#8377;</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="container row col-sm-12" id="wrapper">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success buttonSize" data-dismiss="modal" routerLink="/cartsummary">
            <strong>CHECK OUT</strong>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

icon

```
<i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-flip-horizontal text-primary" (click)="get_My_Cart($event)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="font-size:25px;cursor: pointer;"></i>
```

Comment: can you share your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: @ChellappanV it's hard to do coz API response is dynamically changed if it's a  static api I can..

Comment: instead of api you can define some static variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use `*ngIf` directive ? Show the modal when `mycart && mycart.length` will be true

E.g.

```
<div *ngIf="mycart && mycart.length" class="modal fade modalstyle">
  ....
  ....
<div>
```

---

**Edit: Fix the edge case, trigger the `close` button programmatically**

In Template add `#closeModalBtn`

```
<button #closeModalBtn type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
    ...
 </button>
```

In the component.ts, trigger the `close` button programmatically

```
@ViewChild('closeModalBtn') closeModalBtn:ElementRef;
 
closeModalIfNoCart() {
  if (!this.mycart || !this.mycart.length)
     this.closeModalBtn.nativeElement.click();
}

detele_My_Cart(id) {
   // todo to remove
   //...
   closeModalIfNoCart();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it's working well ,let take this situation I have added one product to the cart and I deleted from the mycart modal now the application page is not working and mouse click,side scroll bar is disabled .I fount a key that the modal window is closed by the default close icon it's not behave like this if I closed the modal by validate the mycart data it behave like this ....So how to fix this @RitwickDey

Comment: after applying this logic the cart gets open after double click

Comment: Thanks it's worked ....only one thing is remaining ,mycart modal is open after double clicked on the cart icon ...I want to open the modal with the single click. is it possible to do ?

Comment: I don't undersand... You're using bootstrap. Why you have to duble click ? Anyway, don't use bootstrap.js in your Angular project, better choice is use to 3rd party Angular-bootstrap component.

Comment: now the modal window is open after double click on the cart icon ,before  it open with single click after applying the above code it happens

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4 with angular4

Comment: Can you mock your code & illastate same situation on stackblitz.com ?. Make sure `mycart` is loaded before click